# 'Apples, red in two of them and brown in one of them, are rotten'

Tags: plural-forms, writing, modifiers

If apple A and B are red and apple C is brown and they are rotten, then does 'apples, red in two of them and brown in one of them, are rotten' make sense? I mean two red apples and one brown apple are rotten.

Comment: That is ungramatical word stew

Comment: @James K ???????

Comment: I mean there is no grammatical structure that I can see.  It is just a list of words and punctuation.  It doesn't make sense and I don't even know what you are trying to say.  Do you have a real situation?  Start with "who" are you talking to and "why" are you talking to them about apples.

Comment: @James K I'm writing my diary to myself

Comment: 'The apples, [of which] two [are] red and one [is] brown, are all rotten.' The words in brackets can be omitted unless you want to be formal.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you, but can I just say 'the red and brown apples are all rotten' even though it's not usually used as 'sometimes red sometimes brown apple'

Comment: Yes, but it could be understood to mean that all the apples are a mixture of red and brown  .

Comment: @Kate Bunting It goes into my diary so don't worry! Thanks